Compare two cells belonging to two different columns
I want to do it in VBA, compare two cells belonging to two columns in Excel and highlight the cell in difference.
I had tried something like this but it's not working.
Sub find_matches()
Dim CompareRange As Range, x As Range

Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
Set x = Range("A1:A5")

For Each x In CompareRange
    If x <> CompareRange Then
        x.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 87, 87)
    End If
Next x
End Sub


You mean you have a list of values in column "A". You have then filled in the values in column "C" and you want to highlight the cells in column "C" who are not present in column "A". Something like that?

Delete line Set x = Range("A1:A5") and change If x <> CompareRange Then to If x <> x.Offset(, -2) Then

@CDP1802: That's the whole point: does he want to check that "C2" is different than "A2" or does he want to check that "C2" is nowhere to be found in "A1:A5"?

@Dominique I thought a 50% chance of being correct was worth a shot :)

Thank you all the solution of @CDP1802 works for my case :) have a good day

Conditional formatting not a possibility?

Make a minor change in your IF statement.
Thats it.
Private Sub find_matches()
Dim CompareRange As Range, x As Range
Set ts = Worksheets("Matching") 'The sheet name
Set CompareRange = ts.Range("C1:C5")
Set x = ts.Range("A1:A5")
For Each cc In CompareRange
    If cc.Value <> ts.Cells(cc.Row, 1).Value Then
        cc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 87, 87)
    End If
Next cc
End Sub


it will works only if rows in both ranges are the same

additional way in case when rows in both ranges are not in same sequence (e.g. A1:A5 vs C10:C15)
Sub find_matches()
    Dim CompareRange(), x As Range, i As Integer, cl As Range
    Set x = Range("A1:A5")
    CompareRange = Application.Transpose(Range("C10:C15"))
    i = 1
    For Each cl In x
        If cl.Value <> CompareRange(i) Then cl.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 87, 87)
        i = i + 1
    Next cl
End Sub

